# Switch to a targeted initrd after setup?

Tags: server, kernel, initramfs

During the Ubuntu Server setup, I was given a choice to install a 'targeted' initrd with only the modules my computer needs. I chose the other option, 'generic'. How can I install a 'targeted' initrd now that I've already installed my system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and change

```
MODULES=most
```

to

```
MODULES=dep
```

then run

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: For reference (couldn't find this elsewhere), my initrd went from 13M to 3.5M by doing this and, on a slow system, pretty significantly improved boot speed.

Answer (score 3):

### Switching initrd type

As you correctly pointed out yourself, change the initramfs-tools `MODULE=` setting from `most` to `dep` or the other way around, depending on your wishes.

**Note**, however, that hooks in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` **overrule** the setting from `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`. A file `driver-policy` is created there when choosing a targeted initrd, at least on Debian (Jessie), that has `MODULES=dep`.

### Reasons for generic initrd

You might be interested in going the other way around (towards generic initrd) if you miss USB keyboard support for your LUKS password on boot. It seems the `dep` option fails to detect the necessity for keyboard support.

Report examples:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771623
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701681

If you like your lean targeted initrd, you might want to include modules `hid_generic` and `usbhid` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` for USB keyboards to work in initrd. Might be `xhci_hcd` is also required if you use a USB3.0 controller to connect your keyboard

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to install the `linux-image-server` package.

Comment: I already have this installed.

Comment: I am not aware of any other kernel flavor, never heard of a "targeted" kernel. Both the generic and server kernels contain the core drivers built-in, drivers for additional hardware is available from modules which are only loaded if required.

Comment: The option to choose between a 'generic' and 'targeted' kernel is given only if 'Export mode' is enabled in the setup.